# Android's Daylight Savings Time change messes up recurring events. How can I deal?

Tags: clock, date-and-time, time-zones

I've had this issue for a while now: Whenever the Daylight Savings time change occurs, Android takes it upon itself to adjust all my reminders forward or backwards one hour-- this happens in the stock Calendar app, my to-do list app (Tick Tick), and my alarm app (AlarmPad).

For example, I have a recurring alarm set to go off every morning at 7:00 am (except Saturday.) With the change coming on Sunday, my alarm app shows me that my next alarm (on Sunday) will go off at 8:00am, not 7:00. In Tick Tick, my recurring reminders after Sunday are similarly pushed 1 hour back.

This is something I Do Not Want. I want my alarms to keep going off at 7am every morning, and my recurring reminders to stay put. Is there any way to stop this behavior in Android?

(I'm on a Nexus 5 running stock KitKat, if it matters.)

Comment: I am curious as to how you were able to observe this behavior since the phone didn't ship until after the DST change in November and it hasn't yet happened again? I have used Android for almost 5 years now and have never once had this happen. Are you associating an experience with a previous device with what you anticipate will happen on the N5?

Comment: There's no "the DST change in November" - it happens at different times in different countries.  Some have already gone forward; he could be describing either.